# Adjust the speed of playing videoview in Android

Tags: android

I want to Adjust playback speed control.

- There are + and - buttons to increase and decrease playing speed.
- Every time button is clicked, the speed will increase/decrease 0.5 time ( -1 <--> -0.5 <--> 0 <--> 0.5 <--> 1).
- The speed change is in range from -2 to 2.

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
 
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/item_video"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"           
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnVirtualPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="OnClick"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/play_transparent_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="OnClick"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_big_icon" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlVideoBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/black_70" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlayVideo"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_marginLeft ="5dp"
                android:onClick="OnClick"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/pause_video_icon" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sbTimer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvEndTime"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvBeginTime" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnZoomIn"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:onClick="OnClick"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/zoom_out_icon"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBeginTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnPlayVideo"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEndTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnZoomIn"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

```js
void addVideoLayout() {
  mVideoView = CourseInfoFragment.this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_course_info_video, null);  
  mCourseImageOrVideo.addView(mVideoView);
  
  videoView = (VideoView) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.item_video);
  btnPlay = (ImageButton) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
  btnPlayVideo = (ImageButton) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayVideo);
  btnZoom = (ImageButton) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.btnZoomIn);
  mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mVideoView.findViewById( R.id.progressVideo);
  
  rlVideoBar = (RelativeLayout) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.rlVideoBar);
  mSeekBar = (SeekBar) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.sbTimer);
  tvCurrentTime = (TextView) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.tvBeginTime);
  tvTimeTotal = (TextView) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.tvEndTime);
  
  // Use this show background video
  Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
   videoView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
  } else {
   videoView.setBackground(drawable);
  }
  
  // Use this hide ProgressBar
  mProgressBar.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );

  // Use this hide virtualPlayButtonImage
  ImageButton btnVirtualPlay = (ImageButton) mVideoView.findViewById(R.id.btnVirtualPlay);
  btnVirtualPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  
  // Listeners
  mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
  // Mediaplayer
  utils = new Time();
  
  mIsVideoFirst = false;
  
  btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    onPlayButtonListener(); 
   }
  });
  
  btnPlayVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    onPlayButtonListener(); 
   }
  });
    
  btnZoom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
  });
  
  videoView.setOnTouchListener(videoViewTouchListener);
  videoView.setOnCompletionListener( onCompletionListener );
  videoView.setOnPreparedListener( onPreparedListener );
  videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    if (!network.isOnline(CourseInfoFragment.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {

     NetworkAlertView.showNetworkDialog(CourseInfoFragment.this.getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.vcampus_title_network_connection),
             getResources().getString(R.string.vcampus_message_network_connection), false);
    }
    return true;
   }
  });
  
  // Use this HIDE video tab and video bar object
  setVideoBarStatus(rlVideoBar, false);
  mIsDisplayedVideoBar = true;
 } 
  
 // Use this play video from server 
 void setUriForVideoView(VideoView _videoView, Uri uri)
 {
  if(!mIsVideoFirst)
  {
  mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  mIsVideoFirst = true;
  _videoView.setVideoURI(uri);                                                              
  seekUpdation(); 
  }
  
 }  
   
 // Use this play/pause video
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 void onPlayButtonListener() {
  // Use this check for already playing
  if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
   btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_big_icon);
   btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   // Use this changing button image to pause button
   btnPlayVideo.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_video_icon);

   videoView.pause();
  } else {
      
   btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_big_icon);
   btnPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

   // Use this changing button image to play button
   btnPlayVideo.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_video_icon);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
    videoView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
   } else {
    videoView.setBackground(null);
   }
   
   setUriForVideoView(videoView, mUri);
   videoView.start();
   
  }
 }     
   
 // Loading use OnPreparedListener
 protected MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener onPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {   
   mProgressBar.setVisibility( View.GONE );       
   btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_big_icon);
   btnPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
 }; 
 
 protected MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
   btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_big_icon);
   btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   // Use this changing button image to pause button
   btnPlayVideo.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_video_icon);
   
   // Use this set background video when completion
   Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
    videoView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
   } else {
    videoView.setBackground(drawable);
   }
  
  }
 };  
   
 // Use this listener touch video view event
 private OnTouchListener videoViewTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   // Use this HIDE/SHOW video tab and video bar object
   if (!mIsDisplayedVideoBar) {
    setVideoBarStatus(rlVideoBar, false);

    mIsDisplayedVideoBar = true;
   } else {
    setVideoBarStatus(rlVideoBar, true);

    mIsDisplayedVideoBar = false;
   }

   return false;
  }
 };   
   
 // Use this set HIDE/SHOW status for player controls
 public static void setVideoBarStatus(View _BarView, boolean _Status) {
  if (_Status) {
   _BarView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
  } else {
   _BarView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
 } 
 
 public void seekUpdation() {

  long mCurrentDuration = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
  long totalDuration = videoView.getDuration();

  // Use this set video timer
  tvCurrentTime.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(mCurrentDuration));
  tvTimeTotal.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));

  // Updating progress bar
  int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(mCurrentDuration, totalDuration));
  mSeekBar.setProgress(progress);

  mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
  
  int totalDuration = videoView.getDuration();
  int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

  // forward or backward to certain seconds
  videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);

  // update timer progress again
  updateProgressBar();

 }  
   
 /**
  * UPDATE TIMER ON SEEKBAR
  * */
 public void updateProgressBar() {
  mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
 }

 Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   seekUpdation();
  }
 };
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: You need to use some 3rd party library that has some sort of functionality to do this, as androids `VideoView`, doesn't implement this feature.

Comment: Please help .............